# Find What caused a js function call using chrome developer tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In my web page, I get a "alert" that I want to know what causes it to fire and appear in page. Is it possible to use chrome developer tools to find it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign new function to a `window.alert` property and print stack trace using `console.trace()`:

```
window.alert = (function( window ) {
  var oldAlert = window.alert;
  return function alert( message ) {
    console.trace();
    oldAlert( message );
  };
})( window );
```

Stack trace is better than caller name because it works in strict mode and it provides more information. But this code snippet will not work if `alert` is called by `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or as a event handler:

```
// In this case stack trace consists of single alert call.
setTimeout(alert, 0, "foo");
```

So if this solution does not help you, you probably need to replace other functions (`setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `addEventListener`) in similar manner as well. For more information you can look at [Long stacktraces project](https://github.com/tlrobinson/long-stack-traces).

Answer (score 2):

You can bind some function of yours to `window.alert;`

```
alert = function myCustomAlert(){ console.log("caller", myCustomAlert.caller); }
```

You can place this at developer tools console and inspect the caller.

You can do this with other techniques like :

```
alert = function myCustomAlert(){ console.log("caller", arguments.callee.caller.name); }
```

The only problem with this is that it has to run on a non-strict scope.

Answer (score 2):

Yes go the page where you are getting this alert and open developer tool and go inside "Elements" tab and do a search of text "alert"

> ( CTRL+F in windows or CMD+F in Mac)

. you should find the line of code which is firing the alert actual code should be something like `window.alert("message which you are seeing on screen");`

or alternate way is right click on page and do

> "view page source"

and search of same text "alert" you should get the line of code.